# Different results using IDLE and running the .py file by double-clicking on it

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.3, and in my file, I also use UTF-8 coding.
The source code includes the

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Using a dictionary, the file translates the sentences of a .txt file from english into hungarian. As hungarian has got some extra characters (ex:ű,é,á,Á,Ö,Ó), they appear different if I am using IDLE or simply double-clicking on the .py file.

The input:

```
The sun is shining.  
The wind is not blowing.
```

Result using IDLE(The good one):

```
A nap süt.  
A szél nem fúj.
```

Result double-clicking the .py file:

```
A nap st.  
A sz‚l nem fŁj.
```

I tried to print the string that contains the results with `print >>f2, final` and `f2.write(final)`, but ended up finding no soltuion.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code output result on the console. If you are on Windows, the console can't print non-ascii chars, but idle can.